# Webapp with UTF8

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, utf-8, tomcat7

I'm working on webapp and I can't set up the encoding correctly. Right now, I have filter in my `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I also add `UTF-8` encoding into `maven-resources-plugin` and `maven-compiler-plugin` in my `pom.xml`. plugin into `textarea` in `jsp` file:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
...
<form:form method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <form:textarea class="form-control" id="newPost" rows="3" placeholder="Text nového příspěvku..." maxlength="1000" path="content"></form:textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="row contentOnRight">
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-1">Odeslat</button>
  </div>
</form:form>
```

But when I send text from this form (for example "ššš"), in my Controller, I get `Å¡Å¡Å¡`.

**Contoller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mainPage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postMainPage(HttpServletRequest req, Authentication authentication, @ModelAttribute("post") Post post, ModelMap modelMap){
    try {
        //this doesn't help too
        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("mainPage", "command", new Post());
    try {
            postManager.postNew(post, authentication.getName());
    }
    catch (PostValidationException e) {
        modelMap.addAttribute(ERROR_ATTRIBUTE, e.getMessage());
        //modelAndView.addObject(ERROR_ATTRIBUTE, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "redirect:/mainPage";
}
```

I also tried to deploy war file into Tomcat7 with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` parameter. But still no change. What I'm doing bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the Servlet encoding is ISO-8859-1. Adding this arg to Tomcat can solve your issue:

```
-Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, I tried to add this parameter, restarted Tomcat, but still same result

Comment: What is the page encoding detected by your web browser ?

Comment: Where can I find this in Chrome? 
When I open page, encoding looks right because text in `placeholder` of `textarea` in `form` contains also some "non-standard" characters and it looks right

Comment: In the Chrome dev tools console, just type: document.characterSet. 
Is there any other filter in your configuration that could override the encoding?
By the way in your snippet, you set the request character encoding, but your datas have already been processed by Spring (I talk about your method's parameters).

Comment: `document.characterSet` returns `UTF-8`...  and I'm not aware about any other filter